# How to upload user profile image from frontend in wordpress ?

Tags: plugins, users, profiles

We have user profile page in frontend. We need to add functionality to user add their profile image from profile page in frontend.

Is any plugin or custom functions available for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [WP User Avatar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware of the native WordPress user avatar is not able to be modified by the theme, or website, but only by the user itself (it would be hard to change a user's Gravatar for example).

You could [update the user meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) with a custom profile picture by utilizing the `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` hooks, and use `wp.media` from the Javascript API to call the WordPress media uploader and let the user upload their picture.

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_profile_picture' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_profile_picture' );

function save_user_profile_picture( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'address', $_POST['profile_picture'] );

}
```

There's a nice writeup on wp.media [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media).